# Pyinstaller and Kivy - exe fails to start script

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I've had a pretty simple Python program utilizing kivy that has worked fine for months. I recently had to change some things and repackage it. I noticed they changed the deps from kivy.deps to kivy_deps so I updated that in my spec file. I can't get the exe to launch anymore and I'm not sure what the problem is. Does anyone know if there were other changes that needed to be made with some of the new updates to either Python or kivy? Even in console mode, the window doesn't stay open long enough to read any error.

Comment: I meant to say, the program runs fine when ran from idle, just not packaged.

Comment: Try building with the `-d all` and `-D` options, and then try launching it from a terminal window. Beware that using a `spec` file makes it ignore most command line options [spec file use](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-spec-files).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was able to figure it out because of your answer. It was pandas importing 'numpy.random.common'. I had to downgrade numpy to fix it.